# read a key of search and put it in a web page

Tags: csv, search, textbox, key, webview2

I would like to read a search key from a spreadsheet and have it appear in the google search box. I would also like to automatically press the search button at the same time to obtain the web page produced by that search key. finally I would like to extract some data from the page obtained. I was thinking of starting from Webview2. after setting the function that loads the Google page with the URL, not being an expert I can no longer continue.
Someone can help me

Imports System.Security.Policy

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
WebView21.Source = New Uri(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
WebView21.Source = New Uri(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

End Class